# (REACT) Devo componentizar apenas as tags que se repetem?

Tags: javascript, react, componentes

Como o próprio titulo diz: Devo componentizar apenas os itens que se repetem?
um exemplo:

```
<navbar>
  <a href="LINK">
    <img src="imagem.jpg" alt="Minha Figura" />
  </a>
  <ul>
    <li>Menu1</li>
    <li>Menu2</li>
    <li>Menu3</li>
    <li>Menu4</li>
    <li>Menu5</li>
  </ul>
</navbar>
```

No exemplo acima, ao levar em consideração que é uma pagina única e os menus são ancoras eu componentizo o navbar, a, ul e li. está correto?

Comment: Um componente não é um elemento HTML. Procure no Google e no Youtube diferentes pessoas falando sobre componentização para então você ter conhecimento e decidir o que você precisa. Chega a ser **baseado em opinião**, já que dificilmente você vai encontrar duas pessoas componentizando uma página da mesma forma

Answer (score -1):

Você pode criar um componente para o `<Menu/>` como um todo e depois podes criar um componente para as `<li>` que repetem. Ou, se quiser fazer uma solução mais simples, apenas crie uma função pra gerar esses `<li>` dentro do componente do Menu.
Mas não precisa de mais componentes do que isso.
Espero ter entendido sua pergunta corretamente.